# Twig template set select control to database value

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a class called Offices which contains id and officeName among other attributes.
I'm trying to fill a select control with all possible values for that class and then set the select control to the value for the current record (stored as customer.officeName)

```
                        {% for office in offices %}
                            <option value="{{ office.Id}}">{{ office.officeName}}  </option>
                              {% if %}
                                     (office.id== customer.officeName)  ? ' selected ' : ''
                                     {% endif %}



                     {% endfor %}


                </select>
```

Any suggestions on how I can update the above syntax to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out

this works

```
   {% for office in offices %}
                            <option value="{{ office.Id}}"
                            {% if (office.Id== customer.managingOffice) %}
                                     {{ 'selected'}}
                                     {% endif %}
                            >{{ office.officeName}}</option>
```